# How to check pipeline and comma (|,) in a string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to check whether a given string contains pipeline and comma  (|,) in a string and throw error if it contain the same.throwing error part i can handle but facing issue while creating regex for this.

i have used this regex to validate it [^|,] but its not working.

String is  "Equinix | Megaport" but my vregex is not throwing error as it contains | in it

Comment: remove `^` from character class, `^` inside character class mean negation, i.e `[|,]`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using JS for this

Comment: I changed my answer to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, try:

```
    var subject = "Equinix | Megaport";
    if (/^[^|,]+$/.test(subject)) {
        document.write('No bad character(s)');
    } else {
        document.write('Contains bad character(s)');
    };
```

Also note that I slightly changed your pattern to include the `+` operator after your negated character class, which means match the character class between one and unlimited times.

Comment: thanks for the Fix its working now :)

Comment: Very welcome! :)